# Mechanism of erosion in control valve flashing

Tags: fluid-dynamics, material-science

My background is analytical and theoretical chemistry, but now I work as a data scientist in the oil and gas industry, working with operations data. The phenomena of cavitation and flashing erosion came up in a discussion, and I am trying to understand the mechanism for what drives the erosion.

I understand the different conditions for cavitation and flashing. I also understand that what actually erodes the material in cavitation are the emitted microjets and very high (but localized) pressure waves that occur upon cavity collapse (possibly also a very high local temperature).

The mechanism for flashing erosion is less clear to me. The condition is such that the evaporated liquid stays as vapor downstream of the vena contracta. Using chemical and physical intuition, I would think along the lines that

- vapor takes up a lot more volume than the liquid. Expansion forces.
- vapor is transported at a much higher velocity than a liquid
- there will likely be liquid particles suspended in the vapor (and possibly also solids)

also remembering what flashing erosion actually looks like - smooth and shiny defects, as if someone used a gauge to remove metal - I start to imagine that the erosion is due to high-speed particles impacting on the components.

But I am not sure whether this makes sense, as I would imagine that very high speeds are needed in order for flashing to become any non-negligible cause for erosion.

Perhaps someone with a materials science and fluid dynamics background can illuminate what actually causes the erosion in flashing?